# HTML navbar drop-down box content not resizing properly when screen is resized

Tags: html, css

In my CSS code, the navbar boxes resize when the screen's width changes and also resizes when the screen is smaller than 600px amount of pixels. The drop-down box and content also resizes like the navbar boxes, however, the content is not resizing properly. When the screen is resized, the drop-down content is slightly smaller than the drop-down box, but, when the screen is less than 600px, it becomes larger than the box.

I had tried making the drop down content width the same as the boxes, however, this had no affect. I tried this with all the classes that is related to the content. None of them affected anything.

Note: I changed the background colour so that you can see how the content wasn't the same width as the drop-down box itself.

```css
            body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            p {
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                display: inline;
                padding: 20px;
                font-family: arial;
            }
            .navbar {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: rgb(10,10,10);
                top: 0;
            }

            .navcont {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
            }

            .navcont a, .dropbtn {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5vh 7vw;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-right: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
                border-left: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
            }
            .navcont a:hover {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
            }
            .navcont a:active {
                background-color: rgb(9,194,36);
            }
            .sticky {
                position: sticky;
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                top: 0;
                z-index:3
            }
            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
              background-color: red;
            }

            li.dropdown {
              display: inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown-content {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              background-color: #f9f9f9;
              box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
              z-index: 1;
            }

            .dropdown-content a {
              color: black;
              padding: 5vh 7.4vw;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: block;
              text-align: left;
            }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #f1f1f1
            }

            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
              display: block;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .navcont a {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                .dropdown-content {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                a.dropdown-content {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                .dropbtn {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                div.tr_about {
                    width: 60%;
                }
                div.tl_about {
                    width: 37.5%;
                }
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="navcont"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navcont"><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
                <li class="navcont"><a href="purchase.htm">Purchase</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Contact</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="support.htm">Support</a>
                        <a href="faq.htm">FAQ</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

As mentioned above, I want the drop-down box content to have the same width as the drop-down box when the screen is being resized. However, the actual results I got was the content being slightly narrower than the drop-down box, and then when the screen is less than 600px wide, it becomes wider than the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify your media query like below

```
.dropdown-content {
                    padding: 1vh 1vw;
                    right:10px;
                }
                a.dropdown-content {
                    padding: 1vh 1vw;
                    width: 98%;
                }
                .dropdown-content a {
                  padding: 5vh 2.9vw;
                }
```

```css
body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            p {
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                display: inline;
                padding: 20px;
                font-family: arial;
            }
            .navbar {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: rgb(10,10,10);
                top: 0;
            }

            .navcont {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
            }

            .navcont a, .dropbtn {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5vh 7vw;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-right: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
                border-left: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
            }
            .navcont a:hover {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
            }
            .navcont a:active {
                background-color: rgb(9,194,36);
            }
            .sticky {
                position: sticky;
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                top: 0;
                z-index:3
            }
            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
              background-color: red;
            }

            li.dropdown {
              display: inline-block;
            }

            .dropdown-content {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              background-color: #f9f9f9;
              box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
              z-index: 1;
            }

            .dropdown-content a {
              color: black;
              padding: 5vh 7.4vw;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: block;
              text-align: left;
            }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #f1f1f1
            }

            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
              display: block;
            }
            
            @media (max-width:650px) {
              .navcont a {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                .dropdown-content {
                    padding: 1vh 1vw;
                    right:10px;
                }
                a.dropdown-content {
                    padding: 1vh 1vw;
                    width: 98%;
                }
                .dropdown-content a {
                  padding: 5vh 6.8vw;
                }
             }
            
            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .navcont a {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                .dropdown-content {
                    padding: 1vh 1vw;
                    right:10px;
                }
                a.dropdown-content {
                    padding: 1vh 1vw;
                    width: 98%;
                }
                .dropdown-content a {
                  padding: 5vh 2.9vw;
                }
                .dropbtn {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                div.tr_about {
                    width: 60%;
                }
                div.tl_about {
                    width: 37.5%;
                }
            }
```

```html
<body>
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="navcont"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navcont"><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
                <li class="navcont"><a href="purchase.htm">Purchase</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Contact</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="support.htm">Support</a>
                        <a href="faq.htm">FAQ</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Very close! The content is slightly misaligned. If you can, please try to improve this! It seems that you only need to change some numbers (I will of course, try myself). For now, I shall accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Udhay_Titus Yep, working well. When it is full screen and when the screen is less that 600px, it looks excellent. However, I made a mistake replying to you. It is misaligned when the screen less than 600px and when the screen is not full screen but is greater than 600px.

Comment: @BlackHawkCH91 check the updated answer. I added `@media` for 650px and `dropdown-content a` padding changed for 650px.

Comment: @Udhay_Titus Perfect! Thank you for answering my question. Working well and is aligned.

Answer (score 0):

PFB code that is working as per your requirement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
                        body {
                background-color: blue;
            }
            p {
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                display: inline;
                padding: 20px;
                font-family: arial;
            }
            .navbar {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: rgb(10,10,10);
                top: 0;
            }

            .navcont {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                width: 24% !important;
            }

            .navcont a, .dropbtn {
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                color: white;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5vh 7vw;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-right: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
                border-left: 1px solid rgb(50,50,50);
            }
            .navcont a:hover {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
                background-color: rgb(30,30,30);
            }
            .navcont a:active {
                background-color: rgb(9,194,36);
            }
            .sticky {
                position: sticky;
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                top: 0;
                z-index:3
            }
            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                transition-duration: 0.3s;
              background-color: red;
            }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block; 
        }
            .dropdown-content {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              background-color: #f9f9f9;
              box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
              z-index: 1;
            }

            .dropdown-content a {
              color: black;
              padding: 5vh 7.4vw;
              text-decoration: none;
              display: block;
              text-align: left;
            }

            .dropdown-content a:hover {
                background-color: #f1f1f1
            }

            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
              display: block;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .navcont a {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                .dropdown-content {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                a.dropdown-content {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                .dropbtn {
                    padding: 3vh 3vw;
                }
                div.tr_about {
                    width: 60%;
                }
                div.tl_about {
                    width: 37.5%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="navcont"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navcont"><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
                <li class="navcont"><a href="purchase.htm">Purchase</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" style="/* float: right; */">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Contact</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="support.htm">Support</a>
                        <a href="faq.htm">FAQ</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not working, this answer is making the entire navbar become a drop-down button. (Everything becomes red when mouse hovers over it).

Comment: the navbar no longer turns red. However, the drop-down content is still misaligned and when the screen is less than 600px wide, the content becomes wider than the drop-down button